# Jekyll Local Server

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

This seems to be an issue others have had, but I can't find a solution.  If I want to write and test additions to my jekyll site locally, I would like to use `jekyll serve`, but all links still point to the github page.  Can anyone describe a clear way to avoid this problem?  I've tried changing baseurl, url, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you using absolute links on your site?

Comment: No, I figured it out. Posting a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out!  The GitHub Pages site uses the `url: 'https://username.github.io'` option in the `_config.yml` and the links on my site refer back to this.  However, when spinning up the local server jekyll defines the url for you, so this is an unnecessary variable on the local server and if you do not change it all of the links will take you to the GitHub page.

Solution: comment out the `url: 'https://username.github.io'` line in `_config.yml` and add the line `baseurl: 'http://localhost:4000/'`.  If you are already using the `baseurl` variable, comment this out and add the above, plus whatever you need from the old one.

I hope that helps others!

Comment: I usually set both `url:` and `baseurl:`variables in `_config.yml`. Then when I'm working locally I leave the `url:` variable untouched, I mean with `url: 'https://username.github.io'` and the `baseurl:` variable empty or with a slash `"/"`. When templating I always use `{{ site.baseurl }}` when possible, this assures me links won't break on localhost or when I push the site to github. By deploying the site to GitHub Pages I simply set `baseurl:` to `'https://username.github.io'` or `'http://example.com'` when using a custom domain.